# how does one integrate $\int \sin(2x)\cos(4x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

how does one integrate $\int \sin(2x)\cos(4x)dx$? im looking for tips and hints on the matter ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sin \alpha \cos \beta = \frac{1}{2}(\sin(\alpha+\beta) + \sin(\alpha-\beta)),$$ with the choice $\alpha = 2x$, $\beta = 4x$.